# Why does the 'transferred' data value in DevTools Network tab shoot up when I open the website in a new tab?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, react-devtools

According to my understanding, in the Network tab in DevTools, the '*transferred*' value says the amount of downloads done by the webpage and the '*resources*' value says total size of resources(downloaded + retrieved form cache) used by the webpage.

In my case, in Chrome, when I copy the URL of the web app, open a new window, paste the URL, click enter, the value of '*transferred*' data immediately shoots up in a second or so to this:[image: 126 MB transferred, 128 MB resources]

Now, if I click on the URL of the webpage and click Enter again to reload the page, this is how it looks: [image: 101 kB transferred, 128 MB resources]

Now, if I paste this URL in another tab and click enter, again the first case appears, the transferred value goes up in a second. Does that mean it has downloaded these resources in a second? Or is it using cache? If it is, then why is it shown in the transferred value?